# The column cannot contain null values. SqlCE exception

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm getting the following exception when I attempt to insert some sample data into a SQL Server CE 3.5 database inside a WP7 application:

> Error: SqlCeException "The column cannot contain null values.
>   [ Column name = Name,Table name = Exam ]

The `name` is also the primary key. I think I have declared everything properly in the `DataContext`.

```
        private void InsertData()
        {
            mangoDb = new ExamDataContext();

            // create a new exam instance
            Exam exam = new Exam();
            exam.Name = "History";
            exam.Description ="History Exam";
            // add the new exam to the context
            mangoDb.Exams.InsertOnSubmit(exam);
            // save changes to the database
            mangoDb.SubmitChanges();
         }
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Ensure that the column `exam.Name` is mapped properly to the column `Name` in the `Exam` table. Check you database mapping whether you are using linq-to-sql or entity framework

Comment: My current code in the DataContext is as follows:      


   [Table]
          public class Exam
          {     private string name; // Local Variable
        [Column(DbType = "NVARCHAR(100)", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public string Name // Column name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                }
            }
        }

I think I have mapped it properly to the Exam table. I think I am using the linq-to-sql as WP7 doesn't have EF yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting the index(es) of The Table. Not sure why it worked, but it certainly did, in case anyone else comes across this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a problem like this modifying `id` field declaration by adding `IDENTITY (1,1)` so my id declaration becomes:

```
[id] int NOT NULL  IDENTITY (1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my current project with .NetCore, SqlCE DB and Dapper ORM, me and my colleague experienced the same issue.
We had the Id Column that's not an identity column in the table.
Couldn't alter the column even

After couple of hours we found that, the model class property which denotes the Primary key column has to be decorated with the following annotations [Key], [Required].

ex:

```
public class Exam
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Other properties...
}
```