# SQL Server CE - Database cannot be null

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, null, sql-server-ce

I keep getting error on my WinForms application whenever I create new database and insert data.

This is how I create the database

```
Public Function CreateDatabase() As String
    Dim ds As String = "Data Source=" + (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments) + "\" + (Application.ProductName) + "\" + (DBName) + ".wv" + ";Persist Security Info=True;"
    Dim Conn As New SqlCeConnection(ds)
    Dim Cmd1 As New SqlCeCommand()
    Dim Cmd2 As New SqlCeCommand()
    Dim SqlCeDB As New SqlCeEngine(ds)
    Dim Msg As String
    Try
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(DBName) Then
            Msg = "Database successfully created in " & Application.StartupPath
            SqlCeDB.CreateDatabase()
            Cmd1.Connection = Conn
            Conn.Open()
            'Create acPassword Table
            Cmd1.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [wvAccount](" & _
                                "[acName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL, " & _
                                "[acPassword] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL," & _
                                "[acKeyFile] [nvarchar](64) NULL, " & _
                                "[acLastLogin] [nvarchar](100) NULL, " & _
                                "[acLastModified] [nvarchar](100) NULL)"
            Cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Create pmPassword Table
            Cmd2.Connection = Conn
            Cmd2.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [wvPassword](" & _
                                "[pmID] [int] CONSTRAINT pmID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " & _
                                "[pmCat] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL, " & _
                                "[pmTitle] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL," & _
                                "[pmUsername] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL," & _
                                "[pmSiteURL] [nvarchar](100) NULL," & _
                                "[pmNotes] [nvarchar](300) NULL)"
            Cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Else
            Msg = "There is already a Database with that name."
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Msg = ex.Message
    End Try
    Return Msg
End Function
```

And this is how I insert the data right after I create the database and populate with table

```
Private Sub ADD_PA()
    Dim StrSQL_vault As String = "INSERT INTO [wvAccount] ([acName], [acPassword], [acKeyFile], [acLastLogin], [acLastModified]) VALUES (@acName, @acPassword, @acKeyFile, @acLastLogin, @acLastModified)"
    classlibrary_vault = New ConnectionLibrary_Vault
    classlibrary_vault.openConnection_vault(strconnection_vault)
    If Not classlibrary_vault.isConnectionOpen_vault() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    classlibrary_vault.initializeCommand_vault(StrSQL_vault)
    classlibrary_vault.addParameter_vault("@acName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, txtName.TextLength, txtName.Text)
    classlibrary_vault.addParameter_vault("@acPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, txtEncryptedCode.TextLength, txtEncryptedCode.Text)
    classlibrary_vault.addParameter_vault("@acKeyFile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, txtKeyFile.TextLength, txtKeyFile.Text)
    classlibrary_vault.addParameter_vault("@acLastLogin", SqlDbType.NVarChar, txtLastLogin.TextLength, txtLastLogin.Text)
    classlibrary_vault.addParameter_vault("@acLastModified", SqlDbType.NVarChar, txtLastModified.TextLength, txtLastModified.Text)
    Try
        objcommand_vault.ExecuteNonQuery()
        txtAccountName.Text = txtName.Text
        'Set controls
        _Main.NotifyIcon.Visible = True
        _Main.NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1, Application.ProductName, VAULT_CREATED, ToolTipIcon.Info)
        Me.ParentForm.Controls.Remove(Me)
        controlManagePasswords()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

At first when I had a primary key on my `wvAccount` table, I experienced no problem but now I keep getting

> *Database cannot be null, the empty string, or string of only
>   whitespace.*

I have no problem creating the database, the only thing bothers me is when I try to insert a data on `wvAccount`. Btw, I'm using SQL Server CE 4.0 and VB.Net

The `.wv` extension allows me to read and write on my database previously, so probably, there's no problem with that.

Comment: I'm gonna take a nap. Been up all night and day for 30 hours straight. :/

Comment: It is mentioned here that deleting the index(es) will solve the problem.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511549/the-column-cannot-contain-null-values-sqlce-exception?rq=1)

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. I forgot to initiate the same connection string I used to create the database, instead I used the connection string for different database. Dumb me. I really have to sleep now.

`Dim ds As String = "Data Source=" + (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments) + "\" + (Application.ProductName) + "\" + (DBName) + ".wv" + ";Persist Security Info=True;"`